# Rust trait impl for generic `impl<T: Read + Seek> KaitaiStream for T {}`

Tags: rust

I'm baffled by this line of rust:

```
impl<T: Read + Seek> KaitaiStream for T {}
```

It looks like it is trying to implement `KaitaiStream` for some struct "T".

But T is unknown, so what can this line mean? Does it mean all things that implement `Read + Seek` will now also implement `KaitaiStream`?

Comment: The short answer is yes.

Comment:  that's mind blowing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax broken down reads as: implement `KaitaiStream` for *all* types `T` that implement both `Read` and `Seek`.

Notice that the trait itself is defined like this:

```
pub trait KaitaiStream: Read + Seek {
   // methods...
}
```

which means: all implementations of `KaitaiStream` *must* also implement `Read` and `Seek`.

These things together effectively make `KaitaiStream` a synonym for `Read + Seek`. Any type that implements `KaitaiStream` must implement `Read + Seek` and any type that implements `Read + Seek` gets a `KaitaiStream` implementation "for free".

Because of the way that it is defined, methods of `KaitaiStream` may *only*<sup>[1]</sup> use methods of `Read` and `Seek`, so it makes sense that it provides all default implementations of those.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> A future version of Rust, will include [trait specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md), which will allow you to additionally implement more efficient (or just different) implementations for specific types. Without `specialization`, those implementations would conflict with the defaults and are not allowed.

Comment: so a `std::io::Cursor` would implicitly implement `KaitaiStream` if it is new'ed while `KaitaiStream` is in scope?

e.g.,
```
use std::io:Cursor;
use KaitaiStream;
let buf = Cursor::new(vec![0, 0, 0]);
```